# How to set the first view in the ViewPager?

Tags: view, android-viewpager

I use ViewPager to switch several views.

public class MainA extends ActivityGroup {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewa,null );
    View view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewp, null);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_search);
    views.add(imageView);
    views.add(view1);
    views.add(view2);}}
```

ViewPager will set imageView as first view. When I turn left,there is no view. When I turn right , view1 will come out.
Now I have one question. I want to set view1 as first view. When I turn left, imageView will come out. When I turn right, view2 will come out.
How to do that ???

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple view then better to use PagerAdapter to add all these view. And then set first view selection like this

```
 ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
 ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
 myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 myPager.setCurrentItem(0);`
```

Comment: Ok. I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @brad Larson: can i know why you remove link from this. Even though link was related

Comment: @Sameer - Stack Overflow is not the place to promote your blog. Almost all of your recent answers did so, and were being flagged as spam by the community. I removed these posts and links as a result. If you did this every now and then, in relevant places, that would be fine, but this was excessive.

Comment: @BradLarson: The point is if you keep link, means you are promoting someone. If link is related then StackOverflow does not have any objection then why you?. This answer'slink was related still you removed it. This link was related to ViewPager Description, so i do not know why this was excessive !

Comment: @BradLarson and one request how can I see my remove post?